# Can you find all package and classe names in a Project classpath?

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible to get all the packages and classes from a source directory (eg. from `src/main/java`) using `Java`? (looking at [Classpath](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/17.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html) and [Package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html) does not seems achievable).

I am open to another language if it is unachievable in `Java`.

Comment: runtime? compile time? source directory or classpath? or both?

Comment: @eis It is to find classes in package, given `String package`, I am trying to traverse through a source directory, providing you have access to it. It is an independent program from the compile, run scope of these classes.

Comment: Basically list files (and folders) recursively in your source directory ?

Comment: You can use library for do it in reflection:
https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

Comment: @AnilBhaskar the duplicate I linked should answer to that question. Basically, use reflections library as suggested.